# Crystal Reports - Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I recently switched to a new computer and can no longer use Crystal Reports when I publish to a server location, it works fine locally.

The exact error I get is: **Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have tried/verified:

- SAP Crystal Reports version 13.0.24.2970 is installed along with SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32 & 64 bit) version 13.0.25.3158 are installed on my local machine.
- Server has SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (32 & 64 bit) version 13.0.6.1027 and 13.0.21.2533 respectively.
- Checked the C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers file and verified that the listed version on the internal file matches the 13.0.3500.0 version in the config file as well as checking that the .dll file is included in the file.
- Checked the server's C:\Windows\assembly folder and verified that the CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.dll includes version 13.0.3500.0 with a file version of 13.0.21.2533.
- Checked that the .NET Framework Version 4_0_30319 and ASP.NET Framework Version 4_7_3429_0 is included in the aspnet_client folder both locally and on the server.
- Checked that the local references (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine; .ReportSource; .Shared; and .Web) are all included locally, set to copy local, and have a version that matches the config file and .dll versions (13.0.3500.0).
- Checked that the target framework in VS 2010 is set to 4.0.
- Tried to change version to 13.0.2000.0 in config file but received debugging error that CrystalReportViewer is ambiguous to CrystalDecisions.Web.
- Tried other aspnet_client folder versions
- Tried to include specific code config file to look for aspnet_client folder

  ```
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="UseBrowserLocale" value="true" />
        <add key="resourceURI" value="/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13" />
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
  ```
- Tried removing all Crystal Report assemblies from the config file but still received an error after publishing.

The only thing I have not tried is uninstalling Crystal Reports and installing the latest version. My coworker and I both received new laptops and he was able to get his working just fine and had installed the same version of CR as I did. Our code matches as well.

The one thing I can think of that may be causing an issue is that the file version on the .dll in question is newer than the file version that is on the server. Could this be causing the issue? If not, can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same problem myself deploying to Windows Server 2016

if installing the MS c++ runtime doesn't help you, this is what I did:

### On DEV Machine

- Uninstall Crystal for Visual Studio
- uninstall Crystal x64 runtime
- Reboot
- Install dot net 4.7.2
- Install Microsoft Windows Update KB2999226
- Install Crystal for Visual Studio (includes x64 Runtime) (V26)
- Fix Crystal References (13.0.4000.0) in reports and calling pages
- Rebuild app and publish

### On Webserver

- Install Crystal x32 runtime (V26)
- Install Crystal x64 runtime (V26)
- Install the MS c++ runtime
- Push New published site to Web Sever
- Remove Crystal Report assembly references from Web.config <-- responsible for the " The system cannot find the file specified." error
- Reboot Azure Server